# How to calculate with input from user in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make a ruby program where I have to calculate the cost of a firms project.

Ex of the variables:

- Salary of an account manager (It has to be user input but ex 9.250kr
  x2)
- Salary of a developer(It has to be user input but ex 9.250kr x2)
- Salary for the top management (20.000kr)
- Rent of the office space per person; (4.000kr)
- Lunch per person (400kr)
- Administrative costs (4.000kr)
- Other utilities:(1.900kr)

But I'm not quite sure how to start the program, should I put them in classes or?

And I'm not sure how to calculate with a user input.

Please come with some advises!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: To get started, figure out what different entities can be there in your project e.g. users, expenses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a service object, something like:

```
# /services/project_calculator_service.rb

class ProjectCalculatorService
  def self.call(values)
    new(values).call
  end

  def call 
   # do your calculation here using the @variables
   # return the result 
  end

  private 

  def initialize(values)
    @developer_salary = values[:developer_salary]
    @top_management_salary = values[:top_management_salary]
    # ...
  end
end
```

then first display a form to the user, maybe in `projects#new` then post the params in `projects#create`, then in your controller:

```
def create 
  @result = ProjectCalculatorService.call(params[:project]) 
  # Save the result or render it in a view 
end
```

The calculation could also go in the `lib` folder or in a `concern` called by the model assuming you have a Project model.

Hope it helps. Don't hesitate to provide more context for a better answer.